# How to pass commanline argument near make comment

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, flex-lexer, lex

I wrote this makefile for running a lex-based program:

```
all:  getf lex

getf: gpplex
    ./gpplex $(ARGS)    

lex: gpplex
    ./gpple

lex.yy.c: gpplex.l
    flex gpplex.l

gpplex: lex.yy.c
    gcc lex.yy.c -lfl -o gpplex

clean:
    rm gpplex
```

I want to modify that such that if I run the command `make filename.txt` then the rule for `getf` will run, passing the `make` argument to the program, but if I don't specify any arguments to `make` then the `lex` target must run.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` interprets all non-option arguments as either variable definitions of the names of targets to build, depending on whether they contain an `=` character.  If you do not have any rules for building those targets then `make` will fail.  POSIX `make` does not offer a mechanism for what you describe, but you can get close by requiring the user to use a variable definition.  The `make` command needed would be something like

```
make FILE=filename.txt
```

The makefile that goes with that could be

```
all: gpplex
    ./gpplex $(FILE)    

gpplex: lex.yy.c
    gcc lex.yy.c -lfl -o $@

lex.yy.c: gpplex.l
    flex gpplex.l

clean:
    rm gpplex

.PHONY: all clean
```

Note that you do not need different rules for the with and without arguments cases; if variable `FILE` is not defined on the command line (or in the environment) then the reference to it will simply expand to nothing.

---

But if you are willing to depend specifically on GNU make, then you can handle arguments without using a variable by writing a pattern rule to match them:

```
all: gpplex
    ./gpplex

# Matches any target name given on the command line, unless it is the name of one of
# the other targets defined in this makefile.
# The FORCE prerequisite ensures that this rule runs even if the target is newer than
# gpplex
%: gpplex FORCE
    ./gpplex $@

gpplex: lex.yy.c
    gcc lex.yy.c -lfl -o $@

lex.yy.c: gpplex.l
    flex gpplex.l

# GNU make attempts to remake the makefile.  This causes the attempt to do nothing
# instead of triggering the catch-all pattern rule
$(MAKEFILE_LIST):
    :

clean:
    rm gpplex

FORCE:

.PHONY: all clean FORCE
```

There is a small issue with this, in that if the user happens to specify the name of a target for which an explicit rule is defined, then the explicit rule will be used instead of the catch-all pattern rule.  This could be addressed by adding `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` to the prerequisites of `.PHONY`, as @MadScientist's answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that, exactly.

Make's command line is controlled by make, it's not a shell script where you can pass whatever you want.  Each (non-option) argument to make is either the name of a target to run, or else a variable assignment if it contains an `=`.  That's all.

You can do this:

```
make getf ARGS=filename.txt
```

Alternatively you can use a default rule:

```
.DEFAULT: gpplex
        ./gpplex $@

.PHONY: $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

which should work... this tells make "for any target you don't recognize, run this default rule".  You need the .PHONY to force make to rebuild the file even if it already exists; if you don't want that you can take this out.